# Parsing text string from a TCP Port listen

Tags: vb.net

I have a TCP Listener that listens to traffic on a port from our phone system.

I have it setup that while the socket is connected it keeps returning data. I have a string called `returndata` and sometimes it will get the below returned:

```
004 HELD    300 8817feb0-a4d8-4a04-8d6b-b4f26b282da4    2ddfe42f-8c42-4373-99e6-8baeaad9bb6f    I   300 53  95e10b5e-2c52-4eff-b43b-5f761f23f35c
```

But sometimes depending on the quantity of traffic it can return this:

```
002 VERS    3
003 HEAD    Device  Connection  Call    Direction   Caller  Called  Trunk   Channel EquipmentId UserId
004 HELD    300 8817feb0-a4d8-4a04-8d6b-b4f26b282da4    2ddfe42f-8c42-4373-99e6-8baeaad9bb6f    I   300 53  95e10b5e-2c52-4eff-b43b-5f761f23f35c    
005 CONN    265 349c9a1b-2e29-4037-9361-cb6c7a384f96    bb902ab8-c356-4cb0-aa65-0c10da857cc1    O   265 07710627585 45  95e10b5e-2c52-4eff-b43b-5f761f23f35c    
006 RING    453 95071123-254f-4e59-a6b2-c8a409d45fd1    5c448dec-ffe1-4862-8a89-9df6636410e2    I   01223894462 1126    50  95e10b5e-2c52-4eff-b43b-5f761f23f35c
```

I need to parse the string so that I return each row (A row being defined by the beginning (001, 002, 003 etc. - for your information goes up to 9999 before looping back).

I need to parse each of this out to a string or an Array so I can ForEach them and add them to my VB.NET Enqueue (Queue).

Each 'Line' needs to be separate.

Comment: Are they separated by CR's, LF's, or both, by any chance?

Comment: Also, you say that you are using a "TCP Listener" to listen to traffic on a port.  Please try to be more specific than that.  The `TcpListener` class allows you to accept new socket connections, but it provides no mechanism for listening to traffic in that socket.  I suspect that you are probably using the `TcpListener` to get a `TcpClient` object for the socket and then you are using that to get a `NetworkStream` object and then you are reading the data from that stream, but if that's the case, it would be nice for you to word it that way.  Also, seeing some of your code would go a long way.

Comment: My apologies Steven. I will endeavor to be a bit more precise in future.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get a solution, the lines were new lines in the stream so I just did:

```
ParsedData = returndata.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

                For Each s As String In ParsedData
                    If CheckForAlphaCharacters(s) = True Then
                        ReturnDataQueue.Enqueue(s)
                    End If
                Next s
```

Thanks for the help!

JML

Comment: I'm glad that worked out for you.  This looks like a decent solution.  The reason I was asking about the specifics is because there may be even easier and better solutions depending on the situation.  For instance, if you are using a `NetworkStream` to read the data, you could create a `StreamReader` class to read from it for you.  Then you could just call the reader's `ReadLine` method (or `ReadLineAsync`) to read one line at a time.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for that I might consider revising my code then :)